# How to find Chrome Driver Path: The driver executable does not exist: error

Tags: java, macos, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

[browser pop-up picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBkrm.png) I am very new to Selenium and want to close this browser pop-up, I need to enter the chrome driver path, but couldn't figure out how to find the path. I am a mac user btw. I will appreciate your helps. Thank you!

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable notifications");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "HERE I NEED PATH FOR CH.DRIVER" );
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.sephora.com/");
```

Comment: This doesn't directly help you with your answer, but you may consider using this web driver manager that's commonly used: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: Yes, thank you DMart. I used WebDriverManager and it solved the problem